# simplifying an algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I simplify the following expression to $\frac{a^{a+b}}{b^{a+b}}$.
The expression is $\frac{({a^2-b^2})^a(a-b^{-1})^{b-a}}{(b^2-a^{-2})^b(b+a^{-1})^{a-b}}$.
I want to simplify the above expression and want to know whether it is possible to convert this expression to $\frac{a^{a+b}}{b^{a+b}}$ or not.If so how can I convert it to $\frac{a^{a+b}}{b^{a+b}}$?

Comment: Something must be wrong, because if $a = b = 2$, then the expression to be simplified evaluates to $0$, whereas the expression you expect it to simplify to evaluates to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{({a^2-b^2})^a(a-b^{-1})^{b-a}}{(b^2-a^{-2})^b(b+a^{-1})^{a-b}}=\frac{a^{a+b}({a^2-b^2})^a(ab-1)^{b-a}}{b^{b-a}(a^2b^2-1)^b(ab+1)^{a-b}}=$$
$$=\frac{a^{a+b}({a^2-b^2})^a(ab-1)^{b-a}}{b^{b-a}(ab-1)^b(ab+1)^{a}}=\frac{a^{a+b}}{b^{b-a}}\frac{({a^2-b^2})^a}{(ab-1)^a(ab+1)^{a}}=$$
$$=\frac{a^{a+b}}{b^{b-a}}\frac{({a^2-b^2})^a}{(a^2b^2-1)^a}$$
This cannot  be simplified to the expression you want

If your expression was 
$$\frac{({a^2-b^{\color{red}{-2}}})^a(a-b^{-1})^{b-a}}{(b^2-a^{-2})^b(b+a^{-1})^{a-b}}$$
then doing the same procedure you would obtain
$$\frac{a^{a+b}}{b^{b-a}}\frac{({a^2-b^{\color{red}{-2}}})^a}{(a^2b^2-1)^a}=\frac{a^{a+b}}{b^{b-a}}\frac{({a^2b^2-1})^a}{b^{2a}(a^2b^2-1)^a}=\frac{a^{a+b}}{b^{a+b}}$$